# Is there an example of a 'first' human error security breach?

Tags: historical

I'm writing something on the biggest threats to cyber security (of either a nation state, company or individual) in the world today, and I've unsurprisingly settled on human error as the biggest.

For flavour purposes, is there any sort of a 'canonical' example of a first/early human error security breach in computer science history I could reference? Something like the moth in the Harvard Mark II that coined the term 'bug'.

About the earliest I can think of off the top of my head is the story of the US Cold War nuclear launch codes being set to "000000" for most of it.

Comment: I'd argue: *That doesn't matter. Because someone used a computer to be stupid isn't about computers at all.* Does it matter whether a computer, checks a launch code or whether the officer that would, if there was no computer allow just anyone to launch the rockets, by being drunk and/or asleep constantly?

Comment: Does the choice of relying on policy and user compliance, rather than preventive controls, when safeguarding the apples in the Garden count?

Comment: My guess hence is that somewhere in an early-day bookkeeping mainframe, a datatypist entered data that someone handed her/him and that therefore, someone ended up with some extra income, and we'll probably never know.

Comment: Or, because stuff was fancy in the early days, someone (programmer/operator) got away with something that he should not have gotten away with (e.g. huge amount of lost data due to programmer's error) because he radiated an (undeserved) aura of infallibility.

Comment: This is twice as hard to define because the definition of "security" and "breach" will be pretty different between now and the 50s/60s – if nowadays someone tells me "well, sure, the passwords on a sticker on my desk, but that doesn't help you at all, since aside from 10 others, who all are also authorized to operate this system, no one knows how to even do the simplest thing with it", I'd probably have a stern talk with him. If this was the 50s....

Comment: Would that include forgetting to lock the door to a World War I telex room?

Comment: Would that include the Roman empire using weak crypto?

Comment: Moths certainly weren't the first problems computers had, but they donated an interesting term.  So from the description of his need above, I don't think "technically first" is as important as "a significant security tale from the early computer era".  I'm guessing this is for an intro paragraph, something like "From the dawn of the computer era, when Joe Schmoe forgot to lock the punch card reader leading to the Great Insurance Swindle of 1957..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at "Crime by Computer" by Donn B. Parker (Scribner, 1976;  ISBN-13: 978-0684155760).  In it, Mr. Parker describes several early computer crimes, including the first documented computer instance of the infamous "salami slicing" scheme that was parodied in the movie Office Space.

All of these crimes took place because of human error of some type or another; either through lack of oversight or carelessness.